# LWJGL 2D Hud Just Wont Budge

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, lwjgl

For some reason I cannot fo the life of me figuire out what i'm doing wrong here. I am tring to render a 2d orthographic hud ontop of my 3d stuff which is rendered via shaders not draw calls. I've spent almost 8 hours and well I suck, please help. There are no errors in the console!

```
EngineWindow.bindAsRenderTarget(); //Set render target to display.

    glDepthMask(false);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glPushMatrix();

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    System.out.println(this.x + " " + this.y + " " + this.width + " " + this.height); //Its at the right position too.

    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
    texture.bind(); //Binds blue texture with writing.

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    glVertex2i(x, y+height);
    glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
    glVertex2i(x+width, y+height);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    glVertex2i(x+width, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glDepthMask(true);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);
```

Comment: gl-Errors are not reported to console unless you query them by glGetError() and write them to console. What is the result you get at the moment? Is everything overdrawn by the hud or is the hud not drawn?

Comment: @BDL The glGetError() returns 0, at the moment the hud is invisible and the hud is being drawn and drawn last.